# need pages to display Title <plugin list category post>

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

My pages that are using the list category post do not have the title on them, and we would like that to happen. Is there some code that is telling the title not to display?

Comment: We'll need to see some actual code or a web address to debug this one. If you can post the page.php template contents and any CSS that relates to the page titles that would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the category title, if you check [the documentation](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/other_notes/), you can see there's a parameter for that:

> **catlink** - Show the title of the category with a link to the category. Use the template system to customize its display using the
>   variable $cat_link_string. Default is 'no'. Ex: [catlist catlink=yes].
>   The way it's programmed, it should only display the title for the
>   first category you chose, and include the posts from all of the
>   categories. I thought of this parameter mostly for using several
>   shortcodes on one page or post, so that each group of posts would have
>   the title of that group's category. If you need to display several
>   titles with posts, you should use one [catlist] shortcode for each
>   category you want to display.